# How can I crawl the page for checkbox/radio/text inputs and detect changes to their original values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

All of my checkbox, radio, and text inputs have '_boom' appended to the end of the id. I want to crawl the page for these id's, detect changes to see if any one of them is different from their original state, and if so, apply CSS to a button called 'save' on the page. Here is what I have so far but it doesn't work:

```
$('[id*="_boom"]').change(function() {
        var sType = $(this).getInputType(); //get the type of attribute we're dealing with
        if( sType === "checkbox" || sType === "radio" ){ //checkbox or radio type
            var originalCheckedState = $(this).prop("defaultChecked");
            var currentCheckedState = $(this).prop("checked"); 

            if(currentCheckedState !== originalCheckedState){
                $("a#save").css("color","#CCCCCC"); 
            }
        }

        if( sType === "text" ){ //text type
            var originalValue = $(this).prop("defaultValue");
            var currentValue = $(this).val();

            if(currentValue !== originalValue){
                $("a#save").css("color","#CCCCCC"); 
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `getInputType` to `prop('type')` and that fixed the first issue.  getInputType is not a jQuery function.  The second issue was solved by changing `prop('defaultValue')` to `attr('defaultvalue')`.  To get custom attributes from an element you need to use `attr`.

```js
$('[id*="_boom"]').change(function() {
        var sType = $(this).prop('type'); //get the type of attribute we're dealing with
        if( sType === "checkbox" || sType === "radio" ){ //checkbox or radio type
            var originalCheckedState = !!parseInt($(this).attr("defaultchecked"), 10);
            var currentCheckedState = $(this).prop("checked"); 

            if(currentCheckedState !== originalCheckedState){
                $("a#save").css("color","#CCCCCC"); 
            }
            else {
                $("a#save").css("color","#00FF00"); 
            }
        }

        if( sType === "text" ){ //text type
            var originalValue = $(this).attr("defaultValue");
            var currentValue = $(this).val();

            if(currentValue !== originalValue){
                $("a#save").css("color","#CCCCCC"); 
            }
            else {
                $("a#save").css("color","#00FF00"); 
            }
        }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" defaultchecked="0" id="check_boom" />
<input type="radio" name="rad1" defaultchecked="1" checked id="radio_boom" />
<input type="radio" name="rad1" defaultchecked="0" id="radio2_boom" />
<input type="text" defaultValue="test" id="text_boom" />
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="save">Save</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply earl3s. If I throw in some else statements, can I get it to revert to the original styling if everything is original?

Comment: Yes you can.  That's a pretty easy change.

Comment: In your code snippet example, let's say I check the box and enter something in the field. Then I uncheck the box and erase what I put in the field. How can I get the CSS to revert to the original styling?

Comment: Put differently, the current example works great for a single edit and revert, but what about multiple edits and reversions?

Comment: With the change I made it will work in all situations now.  Multiple edits and reverts will work.

Comment: You sure about that? I ran your snippet and the styling gets stuck on grey after single or multiple edits even after reverting them.

Comment: I only had the default set on the text box.  It can be added to the other form fields.

Comment: I added that for all boxes.  You'll have to do some more work to see if every checkbox is in a default state if that's what you want.